# rational points on the quadrifolium $(x^2 + y^2)^3 = (x^2 - y^2)^2$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, analytic-geometry, intersection-theory, coherent-sheaves

I have been reading the Wikipedia page on the [Quadrifolium](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadrifolium) there are two of them:

\begin{eqnarray*}
r &=& \sin 2\theta \\ 
(x^2 + y^2)^3 &=& 4 x^2 y^2
\end{eqnarray*}

and it's $45^\circ$-rotated version, which is also a rose curve:

\begin{eqnarray*}
r &=& \cos 2\theta\\
(x^2 + y^2)^3 &=& (x^2 - y^2)^2 \\
\end{eqnarray*}

These equations also have a $(x,y)$-parameterization, which can be found with some algebra.

\begin{eqnarray*}
x &=& \cos k \theta \cos \theta = \tfrac{1}{4}\big[ e^{i(k+1)\theta} + e^{i(k-1)\theta} + e^{-i(k-1)\theta} + e^{-i(k+1)\theta} \big] \\
y &=& \cos k \theta \sin \theta
\,= \tfrac{1}{4}\big[ e^{i(k+1)\theta} - e^{i(k-1)\theta} + e^{-i(k-1)\theta} - e^{-i(k+1)\theta} \big] \\
\end{eqnarray*}

And $\cos k (\theta + \phi)$ for a rotated version.  Here $\theta = 0, \frac{\pi}{4}$ and $k = 2$.

---

Here is the picture of the quadrifolium, a kind of [rose curve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rose_(mathematics)), and when it's rotated.

[image]
[image]

---

The reason I am going to look at this question again, is because I wanted to study the rational paramterization. Let $X$ be our curve, with a singular point at the origin $(0,0)$. We're trying to describe $X(\mathbb{Q})$.

The curve on the <del>left</del> right has no rational points.

Naively, if I divide one equation by the other, I get an expression for the [tangent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trigonometric_functions) function.  In fact, $\frac{x}{y} = \tan \theta$ for all values of $\theta \in [0, 2\pi]$ just as if it were a circle.  Let's define a map:

$$ \big[ (x,y) = (\cos \theta, \sin \theta) \big] \mapsto 
\Big[ ( (2x^2 - 1 )x, (1 - 2y^2) y) = ( (2 \cos^2 \theta - 1) \cos \theta , (1 - 2\sin^2 \theta)\sin \theta ) \Big] $$

And we have that $LHS \in \mathbb{Q}$ if $RHS \in \mathbb{Q}$.  Is this sufficient?  Is this map birational, is this enough for a paramerization?

Here is even another strategy, since we have Fourier series (even just trigonometric series because there are only 4 terms).

$$ \left[ \begin{array}{c} x \\ y \end{array}\right] =
\left[ \begin{array}{c} 
e^{3i\theta} + e^{i\theta} + e^{-i\theta} + e^{-3i\theta} \\
e^{3i\theta} - e^{i\theta} + e^{-i\theta} - e^{-3i\theta}\end{array} \right]
= \left[ \begin{array}{rrrr} 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
1 & -1 & 1 & -1 \end{array} \right]
\left[ \begin{array}{c} e^{3i\theta} \\ e^{i\theta} \\
e^{-i\theta} \\ e^{-3i\theta} \end{array} \right]  $$

Or we could even try a different approach using the triple-angle formulas of trigonometry:

\begin{eqnarray*}
\cos 3\theta &=& 4 \cos^3 \theta - 3 \cos \theta \\
\sin 3\theta &=& 3 \sin \theta - 4 \sin^3 \theta \\
\tan 3\theta &=& \frac{3 \tan \theta - \tan^3 \theta}{1 - 3 \tan^2 \theta}
\end{eqnarray*}

Now these are reading as a degree-map from the circle to another algebraic variety (or scheme).  In that case, why does the angle $3\theta$ appear in a 4-fold symmetric curve?

---

These singularities could be studied by Netwton's method (e.g. [Puiseux](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Puiseux_series) series or [resolution of singularities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resolution_of_singularities)).  Unfortunatley I could never get the jargon straight about the [exceptional divisor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exceptional_divisor) and so forth. E.g. the strategy here to rationalize the [lemniscate](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1531767/rationality-of-the-lemniscate) seems to amount to computing a [blow-up](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blowing_up) of the curve.  At this point I am going to consult an algebraic geometry textbook.

**Example** What is the "[derivative](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3014981/can-a-function-have-two-derivatives)" or [tangent space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cotangent_sheaf) at the origin $(0,0)$ ?

Comment: *"The curve on the left has no rational points."* I can see $5$ rational points without even computing anything.

Comment: Also, I have no idea what your question is, what curves you are talking about when, or what you are doing with them. For example; *"Naively, if I divide one equation by the other, I get an expression for the tangent function."* Which equations do you mean? And the tangent function of *what*?

Comment: @Servaes Thanks... the curve in the picture on the right should have no rational points.  And I am asking for a parameterization of all the rational curves on the left. E.g. for a circle $t \mapsto (\frac{2t}{1+t^2}, \frac{1-t^2}{1+t^2})$ is a map from $\mathbb{Q}$ to the circle $x^2 + y^2 = 1$.   I spend the rest of the article proposing different  strategies for these rose curves.

Comment: What rational curves on *"the left"*? What left? And where does this $k$ in your parametrizations come from?

Comment: Also, the map you define is rather confusing; what is the domain? What is the codomain? Why are there '$=$' signs and what do the brackets mean? And I think you confused left and right again; if the LHS is rational then so is the RHS, if I have not completely misunderstood what you mean by this expression. The converse is false as $\theta=\frac{\pi}{4}$ shows.

Comment: @Servaes The curve(s) I am looking at are on Wikipedia's page on the [quadrifolium](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadrifolium).  I am asking for the rational points on this curve.  There are likely many errors with the statements on the page that I will gladly fix later.

Comment: I still do not understand what $k$ is. There is no mention of any $k$ on the wikipedia page. It is good practice to define all objects (curves, equations, variables, etc) in the body of your question.

Comment: @Servaes See the article on [rose curves](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rose_(mathematics)) they define a general formula.

Comment: -1 Already voted to close because it's "unclear what you're asking", but next reason would be "missing context or other details".

Comment: (+1) interesting question. 
Let $G(x,y) = (x^2+y^2)^3 - (x^2-y^2)^2$. With help of a CAS, I find
$G(X(s),Y(s)) = 0$ for following parameterization of the curve

$$\begin{cases}X(s) &=  (2-2s)M(s)\\Y(s) &= (2s-s^2)M(s)\end{cases}
\quad\text{ where }\quad
M(s) = \frac{(2-s^2)(2-4s+s^2)}{(2-2s+s^2)^3}$$
The derivation is a real mess, so this better stay as a comment rather than an answer ;-p

Comment: [Related](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2536382/solve-x2y23-x2-y22-in-rational-numbers)

Comment: @achillehui How did you expect that such parametrization exists?

Comment: @SeewooLee I just work it out by brute force. Let $p = x^2-y^2$, $q = 2xy$ and $r = x^2+y^2$. I use the fact the equation can be rewritten as $r^3 = p^2$. So I first work out a paramerization for $(p^2+q^2)^3 = p^4$. find a reparametrization to make $r = \sqrt{p^2+q^2}$ rational and then finally yet another reparametrization to make $x = \sqrt{(r+p)/2}$, $y = \sqrt{(r-p)/2}$ rational. Deal with square roots is much easier than dealing with cubic roots....

Answer (score 1):

You may want to find a parametrization like $(x, y) = (f_1(t), f_2(t))$ for some  nonconstant rational functions $f_1(t), f_2(t)\in \mathbb{Q}(t)$. Until now, I can show you that there's no such parametrization with $f_1(t), f_2(t)\in \mathbb{Q}[t]$ (i.e. both are polynomial with rational coefficients).

If such parametrization exists, we should have $x^{2} - y^{2} = f(t)^{3}$ and $x^{2} + y^{2} = f(t)^{2}$ for some $f(t)\in \mathbb{Q}[t]$. Then 
$$
y^{2} = \frac{1}{2}f(t)^{2}(1-f(t)), 
$$
so $\frac{1}{2}(1-f(t)) = g(t)^{2}\Leftrightarrow f(t) = 1-2g(t)^{2}$ for some $g(t)\in \mathbb{Q}[t]$. Then $$x^{2} = \frac{1}{2}(f(t)^{2} + f(t)^{3}) =(1-2g(t)^{2})^{2}(1-g(t)^{2})$$
Now $\mathrm{gcd}(1-2g(t)^{2}, 1-g(t)^{2}) = 1$, so we should have $1-g(t)^{2} = h_{1}(t)^{2}$ and $1-2g(t)^{2} =h_{2}(t)^{2}$ for some $h_{1}, h_{2}\in \mathbb{Q}[t]$. By the way, this give $2h_{1}(t)^{2} -h_{2}(t)^{2} = 1$, which is impossible if we see the first coefficients of $h_{1}, h_{2}$, unless they are constant. 
I think we can use the same argument in case of rational functions, too. (I'm not sure)